# How do I get sound to work with the Nubwo NT-910 headset?

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa, headphones

Yep, another sound question.

I have Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and a Nubwo NT-910 headset that won't play sound.  The microphone works fine.  If I go into **System Settings > Sound** the output is set to "Headphones" and when I click **Test Sound** it works perfectly, but every other sound is almost silent, such as the pop sound that plays when you change volume, or audio in a YouTube video.

I already checked `alsamixer` and "Headphone" is already set to maximum.  I also played around with **HDAJackRetask** and got nothing.  Are there drivers I need to install, or is it as simple as editing a config file?  Thanks.

```
curtice@LinuxLoverPC:~$ lspci | grep Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
```

Comment: Can you check what the content of this file is and post it here? 
`~/.config/pulse/default.pa`

Comment: @Andy `No such file or directory`